# For loop with a passed parameter to twig in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, twig

I am a beginner in symfony2 .

I have a problem in a loop with a passed parameter to twig tepmlate: (show **nbr** stars )

```
{% for i in 0..4 %}
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

The `number of iteration` (**nbr**) is passed as a parameter, I have tested this , but not working.

```
{% for i in 0..{{nbr}} %}
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what you want exactly. put some sample data

Comment: @NitishKumar: i want to show stars , but the number of stars is passed as parameter , so i have decides to do a loop

Comment: `{% for i in 0..nbr %}` ?

Comment: like: {% for i in {{noOfStart}} %} ?????

Comment: @Touki : Thank you very much it works now :) (put it as an answer ,i will accept it for the others ) it works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to iterate with a given parameter

```
return $this->render('AcmeFoo::foo.html.twig', array(
    'number' => 42
));
```

Your TWIG template should look like

```
{% for i in 0..number %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

This also works for runtime-set variables

```
{% set number = 5 %}

{% for i in 0..number %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```